# Import camera from gltf

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to do I use camera from `gltf` in `three-js`? I am using the gltf loader as show in this [example](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation, you extract the camera from the `gltf.cameras` array. It's an array since it's possible to export multiple cameras to glTF.

You normally want to assign the camera to a variable which is declared outside of the `onLoad()` scope so you can use it for rendering. Something like:

```js
let camera;

const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load( 'models/scene.gltf', function( gltf ) {

    scene.add( gltf.scene );
    camera = gltf.cameras[ 0 ];

} );
```